# How to define how many times document was viewed in Elasticsearch?

Tags: php, database, elasticsearch

I need some advice with Elasticsearch. I have a website which is using **MySql** and **Elasticsearch** databases. Searching works good but now I need to define how many times document was viewed by the users?

Should I send update query from **PHP** to **Elasticsearch** every time when user clicks on "open document" button or is there another way to make views counter?

Thank you!

Comment: There is possible you create a counter in your database. And store results locally.

Comment: You mean store views count in MySql database?